# Build Android Library AAR that includes dependent AAR

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android project that uses a library project. The library project itself depends on a local AAR.

What settings are required so when the library builds, it bundles the dependency in the resulting library AAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT bundle/combine an AAR into another.

However, there are two ways to handle dependencies from AAR.

1. if your library project is depending on another library from maven, they will be automatically included in the final app build.
2. if dependent library is local, you need to specify the path using flatDir in build.gradle for final app build. Something like

.

```
repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs "/somepath//outputs/aar/"
    }
}
```